# Segmentation fault core dumped

Tags: c

No entiendo porque aparece el error segmentation fault core dumped en este código de prueba:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    struct estructura{
        struct information *puntero;
    };
    struct information{
        int num1;
        int num2;
    };

    struct estructura t;

    t.puntero->num1 = 32;
    printf("%d\n", t.puntero->num1);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En C, el manejo de la memoria es **totalmente manual**.

```
struct information *puntero;
```

Ahí declaras un puntero.

```
t.puntero->num1 = 32;
```

Y ahí, intentas acceder a la información a la que ese puntero *apunta* (valga la redundancia).

¿ Y dónde apuntará un puntero recién creado ? Pues como toda variable sin inicializar, su valor es **indefinido**: apuntará a cualquier parte, incluso a direcciones de memoria a las que tu programa no tiene acceso.

¿ Solución ? Pues asignando un valor conocido y válido al puntero de marras. ¿ Y como obtenemos eso ? Pues dejando que sea el sistema el que nos proporcione una dirección a un bloque de memoria con el tamaño necesario:

```
struct estructura t;

t.puntero = calloc( 1, sizeof( struct information ) );

t.puntero->num1 = 32;
```

Puesto que la gestión de memoria es manual, **cuando ya no la necesites** tienes que liberarla:

```
free( t.puntero );
```